# How to build table structure in relatively simple CRUD Models in PHP?

Tags: sql, database-design, model, crud

I use simple php MVC Framework, with simple CRUD Models.

Any methods can be added in models, so I can add complex methods with `join` sql-logic, but I'd like to try just CRUD methods, without joins.

So, for example, I want to add feature of adding photos to users' profiles.

I suggest 2  (+1) = 3 variations:

**1**. Keeping photos' ids in users table:

`User` model, and `users` table:

> id | login | email | photos |
>
> - photos is array of photos' ids.

`Photo` model and `photos` table:

> id | src
>
> - in photos table we keep only id and src of picture, and do not know whose picture it is

**2.** Keeping users' id in photos tables (as id of the user whose photo it is)

Model `User` and `users` table:

> id | login | email
>
> - no information about photos is in this table

Model `Photo` and `photos` table:

> id | src | user_id
>
> - information of user who owned this photo is kept
>     so, if a user has 3 photos, there will be 3 records in this table

**3.** 3 tables way:

Table `users`

> id | login | email (* no information about photos in this table)

Table `photos`

> id | src (* no information about whose photo is)

Table `user-photo`

> id | user_id | photo_id (* table of relations of photos)

I think, that the second way is simplier, because we shouldn't parse SQL arrays, it's just simple CRUD action.

But is the first way faster? In first way, when we want to fetch user's information, we know the ids of photos, and get photos from `photos` table by `id` - primary key.
But in the second way, we get photos from `photos` table by `user_id` - not a primary key, so it should be slower.

What do you recommend? May be there is absolutely another solution for such a problem?

P.S. Sorry for messy explanation, I haven't asked questions in English for a while, so you are welcome to correct my bad English ;)

**UPDATE:** I've added the third variation. Is it the best?

Comment: If you started with a single, big, ugly table with every column in it, then normalized it to 5NF, what would it look like?

Comment: 2 Catcall, sorry, but I do not understand, what do you mean? I know what is the fifth normal form, but do you mean I should normalize my structure to 5nf?

Comment: I mean, if you start with a single table that contains every attribute, then normalize to 5NF, what tables do you end up with? You said, "I didn't asked questions in English for a while, so you are welcome for correcting my bad English"; it should be "I haven't asked questions in English for a while, so you are welcome to correct my English." (And your English is really pretty good.)

Comment: @Catcall. So, may be, I will end up with 3 tables: `users`, `photos`, `user-photo-relations`, won't I? And the third table contain a row for a user-photo relation (without arrays I mean). So, keeping relation in separate table is better than adding extra row in either `users` or `photos` table? P.S. Thank you, I've corrected those English mistakes.

Comment: @Innuendo: If you know what normal form is, you will not use first approach. It is horrible. Second seems better.

Comment: I've added the 3rd variant of solution. Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you already seem to know, do not use the first option, it doesn't play well with SQL.

Between options 2 and 3, consider the following:

- If each picture is only related to a single user, option 2 is good enough. Option 3 just adds unnecessary complexity.
- If each picture can be related to more than one user, then you have to use option 3.

So, as far as I can tell, you're looking for option 2.